# How can I connect a node.js child process to a specific tty device?

Tags: node.js, tty

I want to spawn a node.js child process and attach it's stdio to a specifc tty, let's say `/dev/ttyS0`. I know about `{ stdio: 'inherit' }`, but I don't want to connect the child to the same tty as the parent. I know about `pty.js` but I don't want to have it connect to a psudotty, I want it to connect to a REAL tty. I have tried piping the child process's stdio to a tty that I opened with the `serialport` module:

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var tty = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyS0');
var cp = require('child_process');
var myprocess = cp.spawn('myprocess');
myprocess.stdout.pipe(tty);
myprocess.stderr.pipe(tty);
tty.pipe(myprocess.stdin);
```

but it doesn't work for processes that need access to a real tty, like sudo for example. I don't actually plan to use sudo specifically however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up finding out how to do this, originally with the tty module, but I later discovered that any old WriteStream and ReadStream will do, not just tty.Read/WriteStream. Initially I tried creating a `ReadStream` and `WriteStream` by opening the file twice, but that didn’t work as I only needed to open the file once in `r+` mode. This is what I did:

```js
var ttyFd = require('fs').open('/dev/ttyS0', 'r+');
require('child_process').spawn('myprocess', [], {stdio: [ttyFd, ttyFd, ttyFd]});
```

Now when I put the `tty` command in `cp.spawn()` it prints the name of the terminal to the terminal. Commands like `sudo` and `man` that need direct terminal access work flawlessly.

Comment: which node version did you use? thanks